# Redirect PHP Form to new URL

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my PHP contact form to a separate 'Thank You' Page to better track our leads coming in. I just need to know where to put the URL and how. I'm no expert in PHP and would LOVE the help. This isn't all of the code for the form, but it's the snippet where I felt it would be plugged in (Assuming it will replace "Thanks! Your email was successfully sent.")

Thank YOU!
Danielle

```
    if(!hasError) {
            var formInput = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.post(jQuery(this).attr( 'action'),formInput, function(data){
                jQuery( 'form#contactForm').slideUp( "fast", function() {
                    jQuery(this).before( '<p class="tick"><?php _e( '<strong>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent.', 'woothemes' ); ?></p>' );
                });
            });
        }

        return false;

    });
});
//-->!]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You use AJAX to post the data.. but you want to go to a different URL after submission? Seems a bit pointless to use AJAX. Anyways.. look at something like `window.location.href = '...'`.

Comment: Redirecting in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php  Redirecting in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can add a redirect with Javascript

```
if(!hasError) {
    var formInput = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.post(jQuery(this).attr( 'action'),formInput, function(data){
        jQuery( 'form#contactForm').slideUp( "fast", function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, THANKS! I really need to brush up on my code! haha. You rock. Happy Friday :)